# Connect an already paired bluetooth headphone with .NET Core on Windows 11

Tags: c#, .net, windows, bluetooth, .net-6.0

I'm trying to write a small streamdeck plugin to connect my paired headphones after they have been paired to another device and haven't connected to my PC automatically. I basically want to kick off the same process as clicking `Connect` in the Windows 11 device list.

I'm able to enumerate my devices, find the correct device based on the device ID, and identify if it is already connected, but I'm not sure how to enable the music and chat connections if it's disconnected.

Here's basically what I have

```cs
string[] requestedProperties = {
    "System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected",
};
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelector(), requestedProperties);
foreach (DeviceInformation di in devices) {
    if (!di.Properties.ContainsKey("System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected")) {
        continue;
    }
    
    if (di.Properties[ConnectedKey] is true) {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Connected Device Name {di.Name}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Connected Device Id {di.Id}");
        continue;
    }

    if ("<myHeadphonesBluetoothId>" == di.Id) {
        // Not sure where to go at this point to initiate those connections
    }
}
```

Been googling for hours without any success, and given some attempts at the `AudioPlaybackConnection`, `BluetoothDevice`, and `RfcommDeviceService` classes without success.

Comment: See : https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Android.Bluetooth/BluetoothSocket/Connect/php-bluetoothsocket-connect-method-examples.html

Comment: I'm not writing this for android, this is for windows 11. Further, the samples there show connecting on a `BluetoothDevice`, which I cannot create on a disconnected device.

Comment: Code should work on any machine.  Why is device disconnected?

Comment: Because it was previously paired to another computer. I use the same bluetooth headphones for my work and my personal computers. After work I want to switch them to my personal PC to use them there. When I power them on, though, they will auto-reconnect to the last device they were connected to, which is not the one I want.

Comment: Did you close the connection before leaving work?  Windows automatically starts application that weren't closed properly when shutting down.  May be the solution when you start up is to close all open Bluetooth connection before opening new ones.

Answer (score 1):

My big issue was a misunderstanding in the architecture involved in the way that devices, services, etc work.

I was able to get a small sample app working targeting `net6.0-windows10.0.22000.0`

```cs
const string targetDeviceId = "Bluetooth#Bluetooth00:00:00:00:00:00-00:00:00:0:0:00";
const int serialPortShortId = 0x1101;

using var streamSocket = new StreamSocket();

await EstablishConnection();

async ValueTask EstablishConnection() {
    RfcommServiceId targetServiceId = RfcommServiceId.FromShortId(serialPortShortId);

    BluetoothAdapter adapter = await BluetoothAdapter.GetDefaultAsync();
    if (adapter is not null)
    {
        Radio btRadio = await adapter.GetRadioAsync();
        if (btRadio.State == RadioState.Off)
        {
            await btRadio.SetStateAsync(RadioState.On);
            Console.WriteLine("Bluetooth adapter was off. Turned it on.");
        }
    }

    using BluetoothDevice btDevice = await BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync(targetDeviceId);
    btDevice.ConnectionStatusChanged += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("Bluetooth device connected");

    RfcommDeviceServicesResult services = await btDevice.GetRfcommServicesForIdAsync(targetServiceId);

    RfcommDeviceService service = services.Services.Single();

    if (btDevice.ConnectionStatus != BluetoothConnectionStatus.Connected && service.DeviceAccessInformation.CurrentStatus == DeviceAccessStatus.Allowed) {
        try {
            await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(service.ConnectionHostName, service.ConnectionServiceName,
                SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);
        }
        catch (COMException e) when ((uint)e.HResult == 0x8007277C) {
            Console.WriteLine("Bluetooth device is not on or in range.");
        }
    }
}
```

After running this the device would connect and windows would initialize the mic and speaker devices attached to it.